# How to scroll through an array of pictures with PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a sql query that pulls an array that contains file paths to my images.

It is store in the variable `$rows` and I can access individual paths by indexing throught...

IE.

```
$rows[0]...$rows[n]
```

How can I utilize java script to step through this.

Final goal is for the picture to appear with a "Next" "Previous" button under it. 
Hitting next would show the next image (without a refresh)

```
echo $rows[0];
```

would print

```
images/a.png
```

Comment: Create a javascript array and loop through your php array. You can fill the javascript array as you loop through your php array, then you will have your array on js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using PHP's json functions you can convert your PHP array to a js array... and then use javascript functions to control which picture to show

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var images = <?php echo json_encode($rows) ?>, counter = 0;

    function prevImage() {
        counter = (counter<=0)?images.length-1:counter-1;
        var i = document.getElementById('myImage');
        i.src = images[counter];
    }
    function nextImage() {
        counter = (counter==images.length-1)?0:counter+1;
        var i = document.getElementById('myImage');
        i.src = images[counter];
    }
</script>
```

and

```
<img src="img/0.jpg" id="myImage" />
<a href="#" onClick="prevImage(); return false;">Previous</a> - <a href="#" onClick="nextImage(); return false;">Next</a>​
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example to move your php array to a javascript array:

```
<?php
    $row = array("image/image1","image/image2","image/image3");
?>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Sample Array</title>
    <script>
    var jsArray = new Array();
    <?php 
    for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
    {
         echo "jsArray[$i] = '$row[$i]';";  
    }
    ?>
    for(i = 0; i < jsArray.length;i++)
    {
        alert(jsArray[i]);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>Sample Array</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Get your PHP array (server-side) to Javascript (clientside)**

*There are quite a few ways to go about doing this, but I'd recommend [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). It has numerous advantages, but the most obvious one is you can store arrays and javascript objects as a string. If you're not familiar with it, this would be an excellent time to start including it in your workflow, considering you have to deal with Javascript.*

**PHP**

1. Turn Array to JSON:

   `$jsonResults = json_encode($arrayOfResults);`
2. Get JSON from PHP to Javascript:

   ```
   <script>
       var myAppsData = {};
       myAppsData.slideshowJSON = JSON.parse($jsonResults);
   </script>
   ```

Now your JSON object is accessible to Javascript at `myAppsData.slideshowJSON`.

The rest of the work is as simple as iterating through the object with a for loop (just like you would in PHP), grabbing the content and doing what you want with it.

Cheers!